# Rudin Theorem 2.23

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Rudin's Theorem 2.23 states that a set $E$ is open if and only if its complement is closed.

Both directions of Rudin's proof involving choosing an $x$, either in $E$ or in $E^c$. But there is no requirement that $E$ or $E^c$ be non-empty. We don't have, "by definition," that $\emptyset$ and $X$, the entire metric space, are both open/closed, though I know it to be true. Am I correct that, for full rigor, we have to rule these out?

EDIT: The proof is below for context.

> First, suppose $E^c$ is closed. Choose $x \in E$. Then $x \not \in E^c$, and $x$ is not a limit point of $E^c$. Hence there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $E^c \cap N$ is empty, that is, $N \subset E$. Thus $x$ is an interior point of $E$, and $E$ is open. Next, suppose $E$ is open. Let $x$ be a limit point of $E^c$. Then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $E^c$, so that $x$ is not an interior point of $E$. Since $E$ is open, this means that $x \in E^c$. It follows that $E^c$ is closed.

Comment: Technically, you don't need a set $A$ to be non-empty to prove that $$\forall x\in A\implies\text{ something about }x.$$ You just need that it is true for any element of.$A.$

Comment: I think the language is what threw me off here since he says choose an $x$. If this is all an implication -- "if there were such an $x$, do this" -- it would make sense. Is there a difference?

Comment: Well, both the definition of open and closed are defined in the form: "for all $x\in S$..." so if that is what the proof is trying to do, then this is allowed. If the proof really wants a particular $x\in E$ or $x\in E^c,$ then you are correct. Without seeing the proof, I can only guess that this is what Rudin is doing.

Comment: Vacously  the empty set is open

Comment: I can transcribe the proof above. The most troubling step is he picks $x \in E$ and defines a neighborhood around $x$. Surely that requires the existence of such an $x$, right?

Comment: @PaxDaga I agree, though am I correct that I need to rule these out at the start of the proof before choosing an $x$?

Comment: Again, depends on what you mean by "defines." If he just says, "If $x\in A$ then $x$ has a neighborhood..." this is perfectly allowed.

Comment: I transcribed the proof above. It seems to me that I need to rule out that  $E = \emptyset$ in the first direction and that $E' = \emptyset$ in the second direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Rudin’s proof is fine as is, though I understand your confusion.

This is definitely a case where Rudin is trying to prove (in the first case) that $E$ is open, which means “For all $x\in E$ blah blah blah.” that definition works when $E$ is empty, too. To prove that, you assume $x$ is any element of $E.$ The proof still works if $E$ is empty. Same for the proof that $E^c$ is closed.

The definitions for closed and open sets of the form “$\forall x\in S\dots$“ are “vacuously true” for empty sets. But you can still prove them by assuming that $x\in S$ and proving the condition we require for $x.$

Rudin could be slightly more clear, since the book is intended for readers who are new to proofs, but this is a pretty common proof techniquue. To prove that $E$ is open, you want to show every point of $E$ has the property, so you assume you have such a point.

Another way to think of it is rephrase Rudin’s proof as a proof by contradiction. If $E$ is not open, then there is some $x\in E$ where the property doesn’t hold. Assuming such $x$ exists reaches a contradiction. So no such $x$ exists, and $E$ is open.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. So even the use of language like "choose $x \in E$" or "let $x \in E$" doesn't actually require the existence, and is interpreted the same way as "if there's something in $E$, call it $x$, than do this"? If so, this makes total sense. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, I would prefer not to use “choose $x\in E.$” That feels like you are picking one element, rather than talking about all of them.  “Let $x\in E.$” is a little less problematic. I’d say, “If $x\in E,\dots$“ or “For any $x\in E,\dots$” or even “Assume $x\in E,\dots$“

Answer (score 0):

For both the entire space $X$ and the empty set $\emptyset$, truthfulness are asserted by checking the definition. In the case of the set being empty, we say that the property is vacuously true.

Comment: That's not really the question. The question is if the proof needs to take into account these two cases.

Comment: The two boundary cases are assumed to be automatically included in the proof of any basic property of open and closed sets. So the direct answer to your question is yes. It does not explicitly stated in the proof, however, because the two cases are considered trivial.